htaccess rewriterule not working in wordpress?
I am trying to make my htaccess work to rewrite a few pages, like
/programme content to be the same as the content from /wordpress/programme
i've been trying to do this for a few hours but i cant get it to work (even tho i tried to copy the code from a few yt videos)
The first rule "^/programme$ /wordpress/programme/" doesnt seems to work (even when i try on private navigation)
the redirect rules work just fine nonetheless
can anyone help me please ?  thank you
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^\/programme$ /wordpress/programme/
## http -> https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE,QSA]

# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /wordpress/

RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]


</IfModule>

# END WordPress
#

i tried to copy files from other .htaccess i found online or on yt videos, and the redirect wordpress plugin :/
i would like to get my .htaccess to rewrite the URLs from /programme as the websites show on /wordpress/programme 

So if I get that right, then you want to have an additional URL showing exactly the same content that is delivered by a specific page inside your wordpress application? That would mean that you either need a redirection (not a rewrite) or proxy. But that is more or less a guess on my side since your question is vague in what you are actually trying to do and why.

To make your question more clear add a section that describes your current layout. To me your wordpress generated rewriting rules look tampered ... Now is that wordpress application served on the root path of your http host ("/...") or under the "/wordpress/..." path? What else is served by that http host?

Replace your code with the following:
RewriteEngine On

# Rewrite /programme to /wordpress/programme
RewriteRule ^programme/?$ /wordpress/programme/ [L]

## http -> https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE,QSA]

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

With these changes, accessing /programme on your website should show the content from /wordpress/programme. Make sure to clear your browser cache to test the changes.
